# Defining a complex partial differential operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, operators

I tried to define a partial differential operator using this code

```
x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals
μ ∈ Reals && ν ∈ Reals
z := x + I y

landau := (Laplacian[#, {x, y}] + 2*(μ + I ν) (z*D[#, z]) - 
    2*(μ - I ν) (Conjugate[z]*D[#, Conjugate[z]]) + 
    2 I ν - (μ^2 + ν^2)*(x^2 + y^2)) &
```

When I type

```
landau[f]
```

I got an error saying

> General::ivar: "x+I y is not a valid variable."
>   General::ivar: "Conjugate[x]-I\ Conjugate[y] is not a valid variable."

I think Mathematica don't support directly the usage of the standard operators

[image: Cauchy operators]

Is there a way to work directly withe complex coordinates, or do I have always to express differentiation in real coordinates.  I will appreciate any other comment concerning my code.

Comment: i believe you are correct about the differentiation, but also not your first "declaration" of the symbol "types" doesn't do anything, hence `Conjugate[z]` returns `Conjugate[x] + I Conjugate[y]` because `Conjugate` doesn't know `x,y` are real.  You need to do `$Assumptions={Element[x,Reals],..}`, and then the assumptions are only applied by `Simplify` and the like.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you, Can you help me to redefine D manually such that it supports the operators given above. Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: @george2079 I posted that in separate question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143583/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-wirtinger-derivatives