# What is the best way to define Wirtinger derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, operators

[Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) ( also called Cauchy operators) in complex analysis are widely used tools. They are defined in the case of one dimensional complex plane as follows

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right),\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$$

Where $z=x+i y$ and x,y are real variables.
Apparently *Mathematica* does not support directly these operators. For instance, as it is pointed in my question; [Defining a complex partial differential operator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143535/defining-a-complex-partial-differential-operator), `D[ , ]` don't support a complex argument #2.

What is the best way to generalize `D` such that it supports complex variable `z = x + I y`, such that it is homogeneous with derivatives of the real part `x` and imaginary part `y` in a fashion where results of formal computations can be given in terms of `x` and `y`, or in terms of `z` and `Conjugate[z]`

---

### ***Update* :**

Following the suggestion of @xzczd, let me articulate about the concept I have in my head. But the details here are not all requirements for an answer on my question above. It is indeed the converse. As a beginner on Mathematica, any insight can be very helpful for me

Let  denote by `Dc` The wanted generalization of `D`.  The first argument of `Dc` will be a complex function, expressed in term of a variable `z := x + I y`. The second argument will be `x` OR `y` OR `z` OR `Conjugate[z]` (in general real or complex). The third argument will contain a rule of the form `Coordinates->"Complex"` or `"real"` which depends of the wanted output whether in terms of $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$ or in terms of $\partial_x$ and $\partial_{y}$. note that $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$ are defined by the formulas given above. Let's suppose that `"Complex"` is the default value.

**Examples:** (I denote by === the output, I use some TeX code, hope it is clear)

*Basic identities*

```
Dc[z,z] === 1
Dc[Conjugate[z],z] === 0
Dc[Abs[z],Conjugate[z]] === z
Dc[x,z] === 1/2
```

*General identities*

```
Dc[f[z],z] === \partial_z[f[z]]
Dc[f[z],z,Coordinates->"Real"] === 1/2 \partial_x[f[z]] - 1/2 I \partial_y[f[z]]
x Dc[f[z],x] + y Dc[f[z],y] === z\partial_z[f[z]] + \bar{z} \partial_{\bar{z}} [f[z]]
```

I hope it is more clear now, and the concept makes some sense. Let me know if you need further explanations.

Comment: What situation do you want to use it in? Can you show us some desired inputs and outputs?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you. Pleas see my update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one idea for supporting derivatives with respect to $z$ and $z^*$. [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First), we need to use [`SetSystemOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSystemOptions) to avoid differentiating [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate)/[`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs). Something like:

```
old = "ExcludedFunctions" /. 
    ("DifferentiationOptions" /. SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"]);
SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> 
    "ExcludedFunctions" -> Union@Join[old,{Abs, Conjugate}]
];
```

Then, we need to teach [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) how to differentiate [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate)/[`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs) the way we want. To do this we need to make use of the [`NonConstants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonConstants) option of [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) so that derivatives of functions with a hidden dependence on `Conjugate[z]` with respect to `Conjugate[z]` do not automatically evaluate to 0.

```
Unprotect[Conjugate, Abs];
Conjugate /: D[z, Conjugate[z], NonConstants->{z}] := 0;
Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, NonConstants->{z}] := Conjugate[D[f, Conjugate[w], NonConstants->{z}]];
Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, NonConstants->{z}] := 1/(2Abs[f]) D[Conjugate[f]f, w, NonConstants->{z}]
```

Without the `NonConstants->{z}` option, something like `D[Abs[z]^2, Conjugate[z]]` will evaluate to 0.

```
D[Abs[z]^2, Conjugate[z]]
D[Abs[z]^2, Conjugate[z], NonConstants->{z}]
```

> 0
>
> z

Here are some examples:

```
D[z, z, NonConstants->{z}]
D[Conjugate[z], z, NonConstants->{z}]
D[Abs[z]^2, Conjugate[z],NonConstants->{z}]
D[(z+Conjugate[z])/2, z, NonConstants->{z}]
```

> 1
>
> 0
>
> z
>
> 1/2

It might be convenient to create a function to package up everything up:

```
ComplexD[expr_, z__] := With[
    {
    v = Union @ Cases[{z}, s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol] | {s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol], _} :> s],
    old = "ExcludedFunctions" /. ("DifferentiationOptions" /. SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"])
    },
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> Join[old, {Abs, Conjugate}]];
        Unprotect[Conjugate, Abs];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], NonConstants->v] := 0;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, NonConstants->v] := Conjugate[D[f, Conjugate[w], NonConstants->v]];
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, NonConstants->v] := 1/(2Abs[f]) D[Conjugate[f]f, w, NonConstants->v],

        D[expr, z, NonConstants->v],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> old];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], NonConstants->v] =.;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, NonConstants->v] =.;
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, NonConstants->v] =.;
        Protect[Conjugate, Abs];
    ]
]
```

The function `ComplexD` will temporarily change the system options and give [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate)/[`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs) the desired D  behavior. An example:

```
ComplexD[Conjugate@Sin[z Conjugate[z]^2], z]
ComplexD[Exp[Conjugate[w] z], Conjugate[w]]
```

> 2 z Conjugate[z] Cos[z^2 Conjugate[z]]
>
> E^(z Conjugate[w]) z

Answer (score 0):

```
Dw[f_, var_, RealVar_, CmplxVar_] := Module[
  {fn},
  fn = ComplexExpand[Simplify[f /. {var -> RealVar + CmplxVar*I}, Assumptions -> {RealVar \[Element] Reals, CmplxVar \[Element] Reals}]];
  1/2 {
    Simplify[ComplexExpand[D[fn, RealVar] - I*D[fn, CmplxVar]], Assumptions -> {RealVar \[Element] Reals, CmplxVar \[Element] Reals}],
    Simplify[ComplexExpand[D[fn, RealVar] + I*D[fn, CmplxVar]], Assumptions -> {RealVar \[Element] Reals, CmplxVar \[Element] Reals}]
  }
]
```

This will get you both Wirtinger derivatives as a list.
Var sets the complex variable (often z)
RealVar is the real part variable of z (often x or a)
CmplxVar is the complex part variable of z (often y or b)
-> z = a + bi = x + yi

Comment: BTW You might switch simplify and complexExpand if you'd like real and imaginary parts to be visually separated.