# Multivariable differentiating by a complex conjugate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I recently ran into something that should be straight forward, but seems to be incredibly complex.

If I define some function,

```
f[x_,y_]:=x+y
```

I wish to take the derivative of the complex conjugate. I have found some workarounds, such as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91356/derivative-of-conjugate-multivariate-function).

```
excluded=OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"];
SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->
"ExcludedFunctions"->Union[excluded,{Conjugate}]];

Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], x__] := Conjugate[D[f, x]]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

However, let's say I choose the variable to differentiate to be the complex conjugate. If I set y to some constant

```
D[Conjugate[f[x, 1]], Conjugate[x]] (*1*)
```

I get the desired result. However, if I set y as a variable

```
 D[Conjugate[f[x, y]], Conjugate[x]] (*0*)
```

I get the wrong result, while

```
  D[Conjugate[f[x, y]], x] (*1*)
```

It appears that when I have two or more variables, the result doesn't work because the conjugate isn't expanded.I have used the FunctionExpand function, which yields the correct results, but I am more interested in why the disconnect occurs

Comment: This is also (*1*) `D[Conjugate[f[x, 2 y]], Conjugate[x]]`. Have you considered something line `f[x_, y_] := Cos[x] + Sin[y]`? It looks like results are pretty much wrong anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You could use my [`ComplexD`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143739/45431) function, which I repeat here (slightly modified):

```
ComplexD[expr_, z__] := With[
    {
    nc = NonConstants -> Union @ Cases[{z},
        s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol] | {s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol], _} :> s
    ],
    old = OptionValue[
        SystemOptions[],
        "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"]
    },

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        With[{new = Join[old, {Abs, Conjugate}]},
            SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions" -> new]
        ];
        Unprotect[Conjugate, Abs];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], nc] := 0;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, nc] := Conjugate[D[f, Conjugate[w], nc]];
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, nc] := D[Conjugate[f]f, w, nc]/(2 Abs[f]),

        D[expr, z, nc],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> old];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], nc] =.;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, nc] =.;
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, nc] =.;
        Protect[Conjugate, Abs];
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
ComplexD[Conjugate[x+y], Conjugate[x]]
ComplexD[Conjugate[Sin[x y]], Conjugate[x]]
```

> 1
>
> Conjugate[y Cos[x y]]

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
```

It just needs a look at the return value of

```
Conjugate[f[x, y]]
```

> Conjugate[x + y]

to see why `D[Conjugate[f[x, y]], Conjugate[x]]` returns `0`. There is no `Conjugate[x]` involved in the expression. When calling `D[arg1, arg2]`, Mathematica has to look for literal occurrences of `arg2` within `arg1`.

So, the problem is that `Conjugate` did propagate over `Plus[x,y]`. In this case, we can enforce that with `Distribute`:

```
Distribute@Conjugate[f[x, y]]
D[Distribute@Conjugate[f[x, y]], Conjugate[x]]
```

> Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y]
>
> 1

If you add the following rule to `Conjugate`, then it will always try to propagate into holomorphic functions

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate[f_[x__]] := f[Sequence @@ Conjugate /@ {x}] /; ComplexAnalysis`HolomorphicQ[f]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

Now we can even deal with the following:

```
D[Conjugate[Sin[x y]], Conjugate[x]]
```

> Conjugate[y] Cos[Conjugate[x] Conjugate[y]]