# How to take a derivative of a function with a real part taken

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Consider

```
f[x_]=Re[x^3]
```

I now take the derivative of this

```
D[f[x],x]
```

and the result is

```
3 x^2 Re'[x^3]
```

which is nonsense. How can I implement the derivative in such a function?

Comment: Is `x` real or not?

Comment: Is this what you want? `f[x_] := ComplexExpand@Re[x^3];
D[f[x], x]`

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive no,  of course not

Comment: @Nasser, that assumes `x` is real.

Comment: The question to be asked, I think, is how are you defining the derivative.  Is it $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} [f(x+h)-f(x)]/h$, for $h$ real or $h$ complex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you want to calculate the partial derivative with respect to $x$, $\partial f/\partial x$.

Define an explicit complex form

```
x = a + I b;
```

where $a=\text{Re}(x)=(x+x^*)/2$, $b=\text{Im}(x)=(x-x^*)/(2i)$, and $x^*$ is the complex conjugate of $x$.
Your function `f` is then

```
f[a_, b_] = ComplexExpand[Re[x^3]]
```

> a^3 - 3 a b^2

The derivative is now

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}
= \frac12\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
+ \frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}
$$

In *Mathematica*, the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x$ is thus

```
D[f[a, b], a]/2 + D[f[a, b], b]/(2 I) // FullSimplify
```

> 3/2 (a + I b)^2

or, a bit simpler,

```
D[f[a, b], {{a, b}}].{1, -I}/2 // FullSimplify
```

> 3/2 (a + I b)^2

which you recognize as $\frac32x^2$. From complex calculus it is easy to see that this is the correct answer: with $x^*$ denoting the complex conjugate of $x$, we have $\text{Re}(x^3)=[x^3+(x^*)^3]/2$ and therefore the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$
\frac{\partial\text{Re}(x^3)}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x^3+(x^*)^3}{2}=\frac32x^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

You could use my[`ComplexD`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143739/45431) function,which I repeat here (slightly modified):

```
ComplexD[expr_, z__] := With[
    {
    nc = NonConstants -> Union @ Cases[{z},
        s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol] | {s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol], _} :> s
    ],
    old = OptionValue[
        SystemOptions[],
        "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"]
    },

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        With[{new = Join[old, {Abs, Conjugate}]},
            SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions" -> new]
        ];
        Unprotect[Conjugate, Abs];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], nc] := 0;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, nc] := Conjugate[D[f, Conjugate[w], nc]];
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, nc] := D[Conjugate[f]f, w, nc]/(2 Abs[f]),

        D[expr, z, nc],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> old];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], nc] =.;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, nc] =.;
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, nc] =.;
        Protect[Conjugate, Abs];
    ]
]
```

For your example:

```
ComplexD[(x^3 + Conjugate[x^3])/2, x]
```

> (3 x^2)/2

**Addendum**

It is also possible to use `ComplexD` to find the derivative with respect to the real part, as in Michael's answer:

```
expr = (x^3 + Conjugate[x^3])/2;

res = ComplexD[expr, x] + ComplexD[expr, Conjugate[x]]
```

> (3 x^2)/2 + (3 Conjugate[x]^2)/2

[`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) can be used to transform the above expression to the one given in Michael's answer:

```
ComplexExpand[res, x, TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}]
```

> -3 Im[x]^2 + 3 Re[x]^2

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the definition, assuming the derivative the partial derivative with respect to the real part (`h` is treated as real, here :

```
f[x_] = Re[x^3];
Limit[(f[x + h] - f[x])/h, h -> 0]
(*  -3 Im[x]^2 + 3 Re[x]^2  *)
```