# How to solve this ODE by DSolve or NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I try to solve this second order ODE to get k:

$ \frac { \partial }{\partial z} ~ \frac{ \partial } {\partial \bar{z}}~  k[z, \bar{z}] = 5 $

Where z is complex coordinates, so to take the derivative for it, I have used `ComplexD` function defined in this thread:

[What is the best way to define Wirtinger derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143583/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-wirtinger-derivatives)

So that the solution I have tried:

(* First: take the derivative *)

`D[ ComplexD[k[Conjugate[z]], Conjugate[z]], z]`

(* the output gives *)

`Conjugate’[z] k’’[Conjugate[z]]`

(* Second to solve I called `Conjugate[z]` by `x` *)

`DSolve[ x’ k’’[x] == 5 , k[x], x]`

Which gives:

[image]

The question :

- Are these steps right? Sure there’s a better way for solution, but I don’t want to use `NIntegrate`.
- What  does `&` mean here ( i know it means pure function, but then what’s the value of `k[x]` ?
- How to determine the value of `k[x]` for specific values of `C[1]` and `C[2]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DSolve[ x' k''[x] == 5 , k[x], x]` Mathematica interprets x' incorrectly.

Since $
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}[f(x)^*]}{\mathrm{d}x} = \biggl[\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\biggr]^*
$  you can drop `x'` from your equation. Then

```
{{sol}}=DSolve[ k''[x] == 5 , k[x], x]
```

gives you

```
{{k[x] -> (5 x^2)/2 + C[1] + x C[2]}}
```

which does provide you  with the solution of your differential equation that you can use like this:

```
sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 3}

(* k[x] -> 1 + 3 x + (5 x^2)/2 *)
```

or like this

```
ksol = Function[{x}, Evaluate[k[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 3}]]

(* Function[{x}, 1 + 3 x + (5 x^2)/2] *)

ksol[5]

(* 157/2 *)
```

or like this

```
ksol = Function[{x, c1, c2}, 
  Evaluate[k[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}]]

(* Function[{x, c1, c2}, c1 + c2 x + (5 x^2)/2] *)

ksol[5, 1, 3]

(* 157/2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @S.S. On the second thought I'm not so sure that's mathematically correct. There are some fishy moments: 1) why are you using two different derivatives in a 'D[ ComplexD[k[Conjugate[z]], Conjugate[z]], z]' ? 2)  thought CompexD[ ComplexD[k[Conjugate[z]], Conjugate[z]], z] just gives 0... 3) d[f(x)∗]dx=[df(x)dx]∗ only for f: R->C which seems to not be true here 4) Trying to verify achieved solution by putting it into the original ODE D[ComplexD[ksol[Conjugate[z], 0, 1], Conjugate[z]], z] I got 5 D[Conjugate[z],z] which is equal to 5 iff D[Conjugate[z],z] == 1 which is questinable.